# Place Types Is showing wrong type of place on Maps API

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api

My maps api is showing wrong places types and I can't figure out why. Se the code bellow, I've asked for:

type: ['store', 'school', 'church', 'park', 'university', 'cafe', 'gym', 'bakery']

See the entire code here:

```
<script>

  var map;
  var infowindow;


  function initMap() {

    var image = 'http://www.vittoriagardens.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/pin.png';
    var myLatLng = {lat: 25.5244191, lng: -80.4063932};

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 15,
      scrollwheel: false,
      center: myLatLng
    });

    var principal = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatLng,
      map: map,
      title: 'Vittoria',
      icon: image

    });

    infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    /*lojas*/
    var placestore = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
    placestore.nearbySearch({
      location: myLatLng,
      radius: 2500,
      type: ['store', 'school', 'church', 'park', 'university', 'cafe', 'gym', 'bakery']
    }, callback);

  }

  function callback(results, status) {
    if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
      for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
        createMarker(results[i]);
      }
    }
  }

  function createMarker(place) {
    var placeLoc = place.geometry.location;

    var iconType = {};
    iconType['school'] = "http://www.vittoriagardens.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/categoria_school.png";
    iconType['church'] = "http://www.vittoriagardens.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/categoria_church.png";
    iconType['park'] = "http://www.vittoriagardens.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/categoria_park.png";
    iconType['university'] = "http://www.vittoriagardens.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/categoria_school.png";
    iconType['store'] = "http://www.vittoriagardens.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/categoria_shopping_mall.png";
    iconType['cafe'] = "http://www.vittoriagardens.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/categoria_bakery.png";
    iconType['bakery'] = "http://www.vittoriagardens.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/categoria_bakery.png";
    iconType['gym'] = "http://www.vittoriagardens.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/categoria_gym.png";

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map,
      icon: iconType[place.types[0]],
      position: place.geometry.location
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
      infowindow.setContent(place.name);
      infowindow.open(map, this);
    });
  }

</script>
```

I don't know why but on the Map that you can see here: [Vittoria Gardens](http://www.vittoriagardens.com/#location) or in this image bellow:[Print of the map on the website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yV1ZC.png), for example, it's showing a Mexican Restaurant and a UPS Costumer center, and I didn't asked for this types of places.

Does anyone know why is this happening?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

From [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places):

> **Warning**: The implementation for types in text search requests is changing. The types parameter is deprecated as of February 16, 2016, replaced by **a new type parameter which only supports one type per search request**. Additionally, the establishment, place_of_worship, food, health, general_contractor and finance types will no longer be supported as search parameters (however these types may still be returned in the results of a search). Requests using the deprecated features will be supported until February 16, 2017, after which all text searches must use the new implementation.

While the text above specifically states "text search", it also applies to [NearbySearch](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#place_search_requests).

This won't work:

```
type: ['store', 'school', 'church', 'park', 'university', 'cafe', 'gym', 'bakery']
```